# How to handle JSON is null or empty with creating extension string swift?

Tags: json, swift, string, validation

How to check Json Object is empty or null in ios swift.
in my json response contains 100 of string objects , how to check in simply way to each string is empty or null.

this is my code for empty string,

```
var districtCvar = permanentCAddVarDictionary?["district"] as! String
if districtCvar.isEmpty {
     districtCvar = "---"
}
self.permanentCAddDic.setValue(districtCvar, forKey: "district")
```

this is my code for null ,

```
var eresidencevar = permanentCAddVarDictionary?["e_residence"]
if eresidencevar is NSNull {
    eresidencevar = "----"
}
self.emergencyContactDic.setValue(eresidencevar, forKey: "e_residence")..
```

see my json data.

```
"hostel_info" : {
    "e_residence" : "",
    "district" : null,
    "bed_name" : "",
    "month" : null,
    "institution_name" : null,
    "board" : null,
    "reg_no" : null
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an if let to check if you have a value for district and then to check if it's empty.

In your case it would be:

```
let districtCvar: String
if let value = permanentCAddVarDictionary?["district"] as? String, !value.isEmpty {
    districtCvar = value
} else {
    districtCvar = "---"
}
self.permanentCAddDic.setValue(districtCvar, forKey: "district")
```

---

Not the most beautiful solution but could work for you.

```
extension Dictionary {
    func stringUnwrappedWithDefault(key: Key, defaultValue: String = "---") -> String {
        if let value = self[key] as? String, !value.isEmpty {
            return value
        } else {
            return defaultValue
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
permanentCAddVarDictionary?.stringUnwrappedWithDefault(key: "foo")
```

Or:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func fullUnwrappedString(key: Key) -> String? {
        if let value = self[key] as? String, !value.isEmpty {
            return value
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

permanentCAddVarDictionary?.fullUnwrappedString(key: "foo") ?? "---"
```

Comment: in my case i need to check more than 50 values is there any simply way to validate each string.

Comment: its working like a charm, sorry for late reply. thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Dictionary {

    func valueIsNullForKey(_ key:Key) -> Bool{
        if  (self[key] as? String) != nil {
            return true
        }
       return false
    }

    func allKeysWithValue()->[Key]{
      return  self.keys.filter { valueIsNullForKey($0)}
    }
    func allKeysWithOutValue()->[Key]{
        return  self.keys.filter { !valueIsNullForKey($0)}

    }

    mutating func updateNullValueWithValue(_ value:Value){
        self.allKeysWithOutValue().forEach { (key) in
            self[key] = value
        }
    }

}
```

used Like this :

Note `updateNullValueWithValue` is mutating

```
      var data = ["item":nil ,"item1":"","item3":nil ]

        print(data.allKeysWithOutValue()) // ptint ["item3","item"]

        print(data.allKeysWithValue()) // ptint ["item1"]

        print(data.valueIsNullForKey("item")) // print false

        print(data.valueIsNullForKey("item1"))  // print true

        data.updateNullValueWithValue("----")
        print(data) 
// print ["item3": Optional("----"), "item": Optional("----"), "item1":Optional("")]
```